# Branch main already exists

Tags: git, github

I pushed a new branch called "main" to Github with the following command:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Now when I go to Settings → Branches → Default branch of my repository on GitHub and click the edit button, the following popup appears:

[image: Github modal popup showing the error "Branch main already exists"]

How can I set the branch "main" to the default branch on Github?

Comment: I don't know how to set the default branch, but you tried to *rename* a branch, which is something different.

Comment: Have you considered reading this: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch